# Passport.js: How does the verify callback work?

Tags: passport.js

I am trying to figure out the Passport.js authentication mechanism, and there is one confusing point for me.

The following is the `.use()` function's implementation:

```
Authenticator.prototype.use = function(name, strategy) {
  if (!strategy) {
    strategy = name;
    name = strategy.name;
  }
  if (!name) { throw new Error('Authentication strategies must have a name'); }
  
  this._strategies[name] = strategy;
  return this;
};
```

My understanding is that this function registers `strategy` into the `_strategies` property.

For example, I use the `JWT` strategy as following:

```
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.sub}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err, false);
        }
        if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false);
            // or you could create a new account
        }
    });
}));
```

The `verify callback` is provided. So in this way, the authentication strategy is configured.

Then in the API route, we can use `passport.authenticate('jwt')` method as a middleware to authenticate the incoming request.

I check the implementation of the Passport.js (the authenitcate.js file). I found that in fact, the named strategy's `authenticate` function will be invoked for the auth process.

So how does the verify callback work? When and where it's called?

Edit:
After more debugging, I found the verify callback was called in the specific strategy's authenticate function. following is the passport-jwt strategy:

```
JwtStrategy.prototype.authenticate = function(req, options) {
    var self = this;

    var token = self._jwtFromRequest(req);

    if (!token) {
        return self.fail(new Error("No auth token"));
    }

    this._secretOrKeyProvider(req, token, function(secretOrKeyError, secretOrKey) {
        if (secretOrKeyError) {
            self.fail(secretOrKeyError)
        } else {
            // Verify the JWT
            JwtStrategy.JwtVerifier(token, secretOrKey, self._verifOpts, function(jwt_err, payload) {
                if (jwt_err) {
                    return self.fail(jwt_err);
                } else {
                    // Pass the parsed token to the user
                    var verified = function(err, user, info) {
                        if(err) {
                            return self.error(err);
                        } else if (!user) {
                            return self.fail(info);
                        } else {
                            return self.success(user, info);
                        }
                    };

                    try {
                        if (self._passReqToCallback) {
                            self._verify(req, payload, verified);
                        } else {
                            self._verify(payload, verified);
                        }
                    } catch(ex) {
                        self.error(ex);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

the `self._verify` is in fact the verify callback defined in the configure process.